# How can I make a bold font within a code section?

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-rendering

Let's say I'd like to put in a block of a code and I want to stress some crucial places of this code with a bold font.

[B] button placing two asterisks around the needed piece of code, but those asterisks indicate as asterisks within a code section.

Example:

```
<?php
echo $var;
echo 'Some text with one **word** needed to be in bold';
```

Is it possible in Markdown (or Stack Overflow sites)?

Comment: No, that is not possible. I normally use the comment style syntax from the language to add an inline or above the line a syntax correct comment.

Comment: @rene that's sad... Thank you for the `comment` idea!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's see.

```php
<?php
echo $var;
echo 'Some text with one word needed to be in bold';
```

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<pre><code>&lt;?php
echo $var;
echo 'Some text with one <b>word</b> needed to be in bold';
</code></pre>
```

Not possible in Markdown, but using `<b>` inside `<pre>` it works. It appears that syntax highlighting stops working, though, and that might actually decrease the readability.

Adding `<code>` inside the `<pre>`-block re-enables it though.

Comment: How did you did this? Could you explain a bit more detailed?

Comment: (Thanks @ChrisF, didn't think of that.) Note that I added a `language` line in the hope it would show syntax highlighting. It's not a part of the workaround itself. In general, you can simply click the "edit" button to see the Markdown source of a post.

Comment: @Jongware I wasn;t sure about that, though the syntax highlighting might not work on meta anyway

Comment: Syntax highlighting is not supported (doesn't work correctly) on a plain `<pre>` block. You need to change those to `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` to get syntax highlighting to work. It *will* work with the bold inside it.

Comment: Don't forget to encode `<` as `&lt;` and `&` as `&amp;` if you decide to wrap your code in HTML.

Comment: It seems that now, if you have a language syntax highlighter chosen (apart from `language-none`), it gets applied with JS somewhat later, and in that case, any `<b>` elements are overwritten, and emphasis in code does not work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively I've seen this (and done this a lot)

```
<?php
  echo $var;
  echo 'Some text with one word needed to be in bold';\
  //This is the issue!     ^^^^
```

It isn't quite bolding but it works.